# Magento2 cannot load some transaction emails

Tags: magento2, transactional-mail, transactional

Im editing custom transaction email templates within magento2. But some of them are not opening and referring me back to the log files with the following message

```
Attention
The template did not load. Please review the log for details.
```

The ones i try to open are for example

- New Order
- New Order for guest

for aswell as the general ones as the admin/luma ones.

The error in exception.log are

```
main.CRITICAL: Zend_Json_Exception: Decoding failed: Syntax error in /home/forge/domain.com/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Json.php:97
Stack trace:
#0 /home/forge/domain.com/app/code/Magento/Email/Model/Template.php(306): Zend_Json::decode('{"var formatted...')
#1 /home/forge/domain.com/app/code/Magento/Email/Model/Template.php(320): Magento\Email\Model\Template->_parseVariablesString('{"var formatted...')
#2 /home/forge/domain.com/app/code/Magento/Email/Controller/Adminhtml/Email/Template/DefaultTemplate.php(52): Magento\Email\Model\Template->getVariablesOptionArray(true)
#3 /home/forge/domain.com/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/Action/Action.php(102): Magento\Email\Controller\Adminhtml\Email\Template\DefaultTemplate->execute()
#4 /home/forge/domain.com/app/code/Magento/Backend/App/AbstractAction.php(226): Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#5 [internal function]: Magento\Backend\App\AbstractAction->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#6 /home/forge/domain.com/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(74): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#7 /home/forge/domain.com/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(70): Magento\Email\Controller\Adminhtml\Email\Template\DefaultTemplate\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#8 /home/forge/domain.com/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Email\\C...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Email\Controller\Adminhtml\Email\Template\DefaultTemplate\Interceptor), Array, 'adminAuthentica...')
#9 /home/forge/domain.com/app/code/Magento/Backend/App/Action/Plugin/Authentication.php(143): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#10 [internal function]: Magento\Backend\App\Action\Plugin\Authentication->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Email\Controller\Adminhtml\Email\Template\DefaultTemplate\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#11 /home/forge/domain.com/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#12 /home/forge/domain.com/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Email\\C...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Email\Controller\Adminhtml\Email\Template\DefaultTemplate\Interceptor), Array, 'adminMassaction...')
#13 /home/forge/domain.com/app/code/Magento/Backend/App/Action/Plugin/MassactionKey.php(33): Magento\Email\Controller\Adminhtml\Email\Template\DefaultTemplate\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#14 [internal function]: Magento\Backend\App\Action\Plugin\MassactionKey->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Email\Controller\Adminhtml\Email\Template\DefaultTemplate\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#15 /home/forge/domain.com/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(142): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#16 /home/forge/domain.com/var/generation/Magento/Email/Controller/Adminhtml/Email/Template/DefaultTemplate/Interceptor.php(27): Magento\Email\Controller\Adminhtml\Email\Template\DefaultTemplate\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#17 /home/forge/domain.com/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController.php(55): Magento\Email\Controller\Adminhtml\Email\Template\DefaultTemplate\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#18 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#19 /home/forge/domain.com/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(74): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#20 /home/forge/domain.com/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(70): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#21 /home/forge/domain.com/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'install')
#22 /home/forge/domain.com/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/Plugin/DbStatusValidator.php(69): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#23 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\Module\Plugin\DbStatusValidator->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#24 /home/forge/domain.com/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(142): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#25 /home/forge/domain.com/var/generation/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#26 /home/forge/domain.com/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/Http.php(115): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#27 /home/forge/domain.com/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#28 /home/forge/domain.com/index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
#29 {main} [] []
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is a bug in Magento 2 and here is the solution: https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/5116/files

This will fixed the invalid json objects in the order email templates.

See this on vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/email/order_new.html file.

`<!--@vars {
"var formattedBillingAddress|raw":"Billing Address",
"var order.getEmailCustomerNote()":"Email Order Note",
"var order.increment_id":"Order Id",
"layout handle=\"sales_email_order_items\" order=$order area=\"frontend\"":"Order Items Grid",
"var payment_html|raw":"Payment Details",
"var formattedShippingAddress|raw":"Shipping Address",
"var order.getShippingDescription()":"Shipping Description"
"var shipping_msg":"Shipping message"
} @-->`

Take a look at this line:

`"var order.getShippingDescription()":"Shipping Description"`

It needs comma (,) at the end of this line to make it work. So it goes with the other files or template files.

So it should be like this:

`<!--@vars {
"var formattedBillingAddress|raw":"Billing Address",
"var order.getEmailCustomerNote()":"Email Order Note",
"var order.increment_id":"Order Id",
"layout handle=\"sales_email_order_items\" order=$order area=\"frontend\"":"Order Items Grid",
"var payment_html|raw":"Payment Details",
"var formattedShippingAddress|raw":"Shipping Address",
"var order.getShippingDescription()":"Shipping Description",
"var shipping_msg":"Shipping message"
} @-->`

Comment: This fixes the invalid json objects in the order email templates.

Comment: I edited my answer.

Comment: I was facing the same issue because I enabled the profiler, When I disabled it the issue gone.